# Im having trouble with cons cells and I have a question about elements in a lisp program

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

```
((one) for all (and (two (for me))))
```

How many elements are in this list? The book says 4 but I just can't see it. It's Common Lisp, btw.

Comment: Its mainly the (and (two (for me)))) part that is keeping me crazy..

Comment: `(and (two (for me)))` is a list; that list is the fourth element in the list `((one) for all (and (two (for me))))` (which contains one other list and two symbols).

Comment: so there are three elements? "one" "forall" "(and (two(for me ))))"

Answer (score 3):

In the list `((one) for all (and (two (for me))))`, there are four elements: the list `(one)`, the symbol `for`, the symbol `all`, and the list `(and (two (for me)))`.

When you have questions like this, experimenting at the REPL can be helpful:

```
CL-USER> (setf my-list '())
NIL
CL-USER> (length my-list)
0
```

We have created the empty list `my-list`, and checked its length.

```
CL-USER> (setf my-sublist '(and (two (for me))))
(AND (TWO (FOR ME)))
CL-USER> (length my-sublist)
2
```

We have created another list, `my-sublist`. Note that this list contains the symbol `and`, and the list `(two (for me))`. The result returned by `length` verifies that `my-sublist` contains two elements (one symbol and one list).

```
CL-USER> (setf my-list (cons my-sublist my-list))
((AND (TWO (FOR ME))))
CL-USER> (length my-list)
1
```

We have `cons`ed `my-sublist` onto `my-list`, to create a list containing one element, which is the list `(and (two (for me)))`. Note that the list `my-sublist`, i.e. the list `(and (two (for me)))` contains *two* elements, but the list `my-list` -- at the moment, `((and (two (for me))))` -- contains only *one* element, namely the list `my-sublist`.

```
CL-USER> (setf my-list (cons 'all my-list))
(ALL (AND (TWO (FOR ME))))
CL-USER> (length my-list)
2
CL-USER> (setf my-list (cons 'for my-list))
(FOR ALL (AND (TWO (FOR ME))))
CL-USER> (length my-list)
3
CL-USER> (setf my-list (cons '(one) my-list))
((ONE) FOR ALL (AND (TWO (FOR ME))))
CL-USER> (length my-list)
4
```

We have added the remaining three elements (the symbols `all` and `for`, and the list `(one)`. The result is a list of four elements, as expected.

Answer (score 3):

```
CL-USER 14 > (do ((list '((one) for all (and (two (for me)))) (rest list))
                  (i 1 (1+ i)))
                 ((null list))
               (terpri)
               (princ "Element ")
               (princ i)
               (princ " is ")
               (princ (first list)))

Element 1 is (ONE)
Element 2 is FOR
Element 3 is ALL
Element 4 is (AND (TWO (FOR ME)))
NIL
```